# I need to clean up some xml another parser missed

Tags: asp.net

The symbol I need to get rid of is & (except when it's correctly used in a escape sequence of course). So I want to find all the "Mr. & Mrs. Jones" and replrace them with "Mr. `&amp;` Mrs". So I'm looing for all instances of " &", or "& ". And I need to replace them with &

Sure sounds like a job for RegEx; which I SUCK AT! But I envy it if that helps.

Any Thanksgiving Answeres out there for me?

Comment: Seems to work great for all cases. I don't know how all you guys find the time to come up with all these great answers, but I'm sure glad you do! THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"&(?!\w+;|#\d+;|#x[0-9a-fA-F]+;)", "&amp;");
```

This will replace any orphan `&` for correct escaped sequence.

Comment: Hmm... I didn't think about other escape sequences... My bad, good regex, would have written the same thing if I could have remembered the post conditions syntax...

Comment: ty LorenVS; btw, `&nbsp;` can't be inside a standalone valid XML file, because it isnt a predefined character entity, like `&amp;`, `&lt;`, `&gt;`, `&apos;` and `&quot;`

Comment: @Ruben, you can use CDATA to include text in an XML document so it can be if needed.

Comment: You would probably want to detect the numeric character references too, eg. `&(?!\w+;|#\d+;|#x[0-9a-fA-F]+;)`. This would still break valid `&` in a comment or CDATA section.

Comment: @bobince, nice catch, I updated answer with your regex; about CDATA sections, we cant properly deal with it using regexps

Answer (score 0):

Use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(your string)`?

Comment: What do you think will happen to the < and > characters?

Answer (score -1):

If you're doing plain old string operations, the simplest (albeit probably not the most efficient) way to accomplish this is to just use two replaces:

```
string xml = "Mr. & Mrs. Jones &nbsp;";
xml = xml.Replace("&", "&nbsp;");
xml = xml.Replace("&nbsp;&nbsp;", "&nbsp;");
```

You could probably use a StringBuilder and build a quick loop that looks for all the "&" which would work pretty well as well...

Regex would work great too, but I always forget post conditions...

**Edit: Forgot about other escape sequences, so this solution is incomplete at best **